# What is the accepted "best practice" method to structure an A-Frame project's files?

Tags: aframe

When making an A-Frame project I unintentionally use varying directory structures which trips me up when switching between my own and other people's projects.

What is the "best" way to structure an A-Frame project to keep it consistent with others? Is there any best practice or is this just personal preference?

For example (static project):

```
/index.html
/models/
/images/
/js/
/lib/
/audio/
```

or maybe

```
/index.html
/assets/images/
/assets/models/
/js/
/js/lib/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some good examples!

- Boilerplate: https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-super-hot-loader/tree/master/example
- Production Project: https://github.com/supermedium/moonrider

```
    assets/
      models/
      img/
      sounds/
    src/
      index.js
      components/
        shaders/
      scene.html
    index.html
    package.json
    webpack.config.js
```